# Ionic 2 unable to post to asp dotnet core even with CORS enabled

Tags: angular, ionic2, .net-core

I have tried to look for answer, some are close but not what I am looking for.

This is my issue, I am developing an Ionic app and currently devving in the web browser view. I am unable to post any content back to my asp dotnet core backend.

My stack is as follows:
Front-End

- Ionic 2 - Latest version using latest version of Angular 4
- Nginx - as my proxy server
- Docker - as my container running dotnet core applications

Here is the code for the post I am trying:

```
let body =JSON.stringify({ 'username': username, 'password': password }); 
let options = new RequestOptions({headers:new Headers()});
options.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
options.headers.set( 'Accept', 'application/json' );

return this.http.post(this.loginUrl,body,options)
  .map((res: Response) => res.json())
  .catch((error: any) => {
    console.log("ERROR", error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error')
  })
```

My Proxy has

```
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
```

And my backed has the following CORS configuration in Startup.cs

```
            options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
            builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowCredentials());
        });
```

and in the Configure function

```
            app.UseMvc().UseCors("CorsPolicy");
```

I see in the output window in Visual Studio 2017 that the response is reaching the container:

```
Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured): {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.Request","time":"2017-07-15T19:29:10.5330300Z","tags":{"ai.internal.nodeName":"9a9595bd67c1","ai.operation.id":"0HL6BMO90PHKC","ai.application.ver":"1.0.0.0","ai.operation.name":"OPTIONS Users/AuthenticateUser","ai.internal.sdkVersion":"aspnet5c:2.0.0","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"9a9595bd67c1","ai.location.ip":"172.18.0.5"},"data":{"baseType":"RequestData","baseData":{"ver":2,"id":"HKmnWfByHeU=","name":"OPTIONS Users/AuthenticateUser","duration":"00:00:11.2837000","success":false,"responseCode":"415","url":"http://leo.users/users/authenticate","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true","httpMethod":"OPTIONS","AspNetCoreEnvironment":"Development"}}}}
```

I have tried multiple ways to set the headers on the Ionic 2 side.
I am not sure what to do/if I am just missing something. Help would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Well first of all you don't need cors because you have proxies for the local serve (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-proxy-example/blob/master/ionic.project) and the mobile doesn't require cors at all because it doesn't use such policies. If you really want find out why your CORS is not working you can look at your request/response headers to see if the all the headers are there

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have to have CORS.  I am designing a microservices architecture. At the moment this means that I have the proxy running in one docker container and two other microservices running in separate cotainers. Because of that the way i access my services from my proxy is as such `http://service.name` .I realize  that for running on mobile device I wont have these issues. But  for now I am developing in my web browser and need to find a way to sort this issue out. Because I will be developing a webpage as well in angular 2 and I assume I will be facing the same issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [misha130](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2490286/misha130) for the comment above. This solved my issue.

I just had to update my ionic proxy file and add:

```
    {
        "path": "/users",
        "proxyUrl": "http://localhost:8080/users"
    }
```

Thanks again.